# Deploy SyncFusion Report Server IIS Server Login Prompt

Tags: authentication, iis, reporting-services, syncfusion, windows-server-2016

I just installed the latest version of SyncFusion Report Server and am running it in Microsoft IIS / Server 2016.

I created a subdomain (reports.mydomain.com) and created a binding in iis. I can hit that website and it opens the login page for the syncFusion report server.

When I go to my website (reports.myWebsite.com) I get the standard login for syncFusion. I then login with my SyncFusion credentials and it then prompts me with a server login. I can't figure out how to get around this server login prompt. If I use my server credentials and login then it works but I don't want to have to do that. The report server is running under port 57240.

Just for testing purposes, my firewall is completely disabled and I gave full access to the report server's application pool to the SyncFusion directory.

I created an iis binding for port 57240 and a binding for reports.mydomain.com on port 80.

SyncFusion does offer the ability to use windows authentication to login. I am curious if it is trying to windows authenticate first before basic authenticate. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got off the phone with Syncfusion and it turns out that SQL Server Reporting Services automatically registers the URL /reports. I switched my ssrs url to /ssrsreports and everything is now working.

A big thanks to Syncfusion for setting up a GoToMeeting and figuring this out for me!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the Authentication of your application is set by this way ? 
(Open IIS -> Select your Web Application -> Double click on the “Authentication” listed in the main panel)

[image]

i.  Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation should be Disabled 
ii. Forms Authentication and Anonymous Authentication should be Enabled

Comment: The server login prompt does say "Your connection to this site is not private". Does Syncfusion require an SSL to connect externally?